# How to use the bash command 'which' from QProcess

Tags: c++, bash, qt, qprocess

I'm a student programmer using Qt and I seem to have ran into an issue using QProcess to launch the bash command 'which' in an attempt to collect a map of installations of an application. I have the following code and I'm truly lost as to what I might be missing. I have referenced the [QProcess documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html) and still cant figure out whats wrong.

Every time this code is ran the file is not created in the indicated directory. Without the file constructed the application cannot proceed.

```
//datatypes
QProcess *findFiles = new QProcess();
QStringList arguments;
QStringList InstallationList;
QString program = "/bin/bash";
QString currentUsersHomeDirectory = QDir::homePath();
QString tmpScriptLocation = currentUsersHomeDirectory;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
//generate file with list of files found
tmpScriptLocation += ".whichBAScriptOutput";
arguments << QString(QString("which -a certainFile >> ") += tmpScriptLocation);
findFiles->setProcessEnvironment(env);
findFiles->start(program,arguments);
findFiles->waitForFinished();
```

Comment: not sure what QT and QProcess are, but you'll do better if you add debugging information that prints out the final value of all variables that you're using. If that doesn't make it obvious what the problem is, then edit your question about with the output of your debugging. Good luck.

Comment: Do you really need the file or just the output of `which`? If the latter, there is no need to redirect to file first. You can directly read the standard output via `readAll()`/`readAllStandardOutput()`. Either do it after your process has finished or use the `readyReadStandardOutput()` signal to get notified while the process is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*which* is located on */usr/bin/* so try to change the path..

**EDIT**:
You need to connect *QProcess*'s signal *readyReadStandardOutput()* to your slot. Actually if you take a look at the documentation *QProcess* inherits from *QIODevice*. This means you can do something  like:

```
while(canReadLine()){
   string line = readLine();
   ...
}
```

if you have already written a client-server application in Qt, i am sure you reconized the pseudocode..

Comment: Awesome! I don't know why I didn't think of this! You have me closer but I need to get the output from this command stored in into a QStringList(or a file). Any advice? Good Catch by the way!

Comment: Magnific solution! :D (neanche letta! piegato!)

Answer (score 0):

As you say you want to execute `which`, but you are lauching `bash` with a handwritten script. There is a much easier way to do this in a sequential manner:

```
//preparing the job, 
QProcess process;
QString processName = "which"; //or absoute path if not in path
QStringList arguments = QStringList() << "-a" 
                                      << "certainFile.txt";

// process.setWorkingDirectory() //if you want it to execute in a specific directory

//start the process                                  
process.start(processName, arguments ); 
//sit back and wait                                     
process.waitForStarted(); //blocking, return bool
process.waitForFinished(); //blocking, return bool                                      
if(process.exitCode() != 0){
  //Something went wrong
}

//return a byte array containing what the command "which" print in console
QByteArray processOutput = process.readAll();
```